# Spotify API Error 401 - "Permissions Missing"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

Using the spotify web API, I'm getting a 401 error - "Permissions missing" when trying to fetch a track that is currently playing, even after reauthenticating the user.

Here are my scopes:

```
        const scope = [
        "user-read-email",
        "user-read-private",            
        "user-modify-playback-state",
        "user-read-playback-state",
        "user-read-currently-playing",
        "user-read-recently-played",
        "user-read-playback-position",
        "user-top-read",
    ]
    // brings us to the new url with our variables
    window.location.href = `${apiUrl}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}&scope=&${scope.join(
        " "
    )}&response_type=token&show_dialog=true`
```

And here is the Request URL from when I check in Network:
[Network Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkQSm.png)

Here is the authorization screen I get, which looks different from the tutorials: [Authorization Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7qmq.png)

This is the call that fails:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      const getCurrentTrack = async() => {
          const response = await axios.get(
              'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing', 
              {
              headers: {
                  Authorization:"Bearer " +token,
                  "Content-Type": "application/json"
              }
          })
          console.log(response)
      }
      getCurrentTrack()
  }, [token, dispatch])
```

and here is the error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Permissions missing"
  }
}
```

Also, I'm able to get other API calls working, like getting playlists and user info, and am only getting an error with this call so far.
I even tried creating a new project in the dashboard, but nothing has worked so far. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You got `scope=&` in the login URL you are creating, that `&` doesn't belong there. You passed an _empty_ value for the scope parameter here, and as the documentation explains, in that case it automatically falls back to a few default scopes.

Comment: To be clear, you should remove the `&` where you specify `scope=&`.